# `$("non_existing_element");` returns `[ ]` in Console but `ReferenceError` when called as a variable in Console

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var someVar = $("non_existing_element");
});
```

In browser console

```
> $("non_existing_element");
[]
```

BUT

```
> someVar
ReferenceError: someVar is not defined
```

Why is that implemented this way? Wouldn't make much more sense if calling `someVar` also returned `[]` or at least that both calls returned the same thing?

Comment: Because `someVar` exists only in the `document ready` scope because you declared it as `var someVar`? Try with `someVar = $("non_existing_element");`

Comment: Your `someVar` variable is scoped to the anonymous function passed to the `ready()` function, and therefore not visible to the console. It's implemented that way so JavaScript actually has a concept of variable scope, rather than everything being visible to everything else.

Comment: Downvoters please stop [jumping to conclusions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_to_conclusions) and look at my comment to *Kyle Macey*'s answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## <strike>30</strike> 90 seconds about variable scoping

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var someVar = $("non_existing_element");
});
```

At this point, `someVar` does, in fact equal `[]`. So if you were to write:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var someVar = $("non_existing_element");
  console.log("the value of someVar is", someVar);
});
```

You would see in your console

> The value of someVar is []

Hooray!

But!

As soon as you pass that last curly bracket...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var someVar = $("non_existing_element");
}); // <<<<< This one
```

You have **left the function** defined by `function() {}`. Notice, it has no name, so this is called an *anonymous* function. Don't worry, it does not have a vendetta against politics or the economy.

Once you leave the function, variables defined with `var` are no longer accessible. This is to prevent *scope leak*, which is a whole other conversation, which I'm sure you'll be learning about very soon. Try defining it without `var`. See what happens.

Not using `var` will allow the variable to escape the clutch of the wretched anonymous function, and crap itself all over your global scope. (which, by the way is accessible through `window.global_variable`)

So, when you type a variable into your console (does not apply if you're using [breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-dynamic-javascript)), variables are read from your global scope, since you are not *inside* any function. And since we just discovered that `var` scoped the variable to the function you're not in, we now know why it is undefined.

I mean, imagine if there could only be one variable named `checkbox`! Every Javascript plugin you put in would conflict with each other. No one would know what `checkbox` was, and before you know it, crazy stuff is happening all over your DOM.

Moral of the story: Scope your variables. Understand your variables. Love your variables.

Comment: Technically saying "At this point, someVar does, in fact equal []" is wrong, since it doesn't. It's a jQuery object containing an empty set, and there's not even any guarantee that it will be displayed as "[]" in the console of every browser.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist my answer was targeted toward the person who asked the question. So, he tells me he sees `someVar` defined as `[]`, then I'm going to answer based off that.

Comment: I knew about all concepts mentioned in your answer(except the term *scope leak*). But thank you nevertheless. One time I had some variable inside document ready defined but I could call it in the console(looking back, this must have been defined somewhere else then). I then concluded that it was programmed in the jQuery code that when the `$` sign was applied to document and called with the `ready` method it automatically converted all variables in this function(but not variables inside a deeper nested function) to the global scope. I thought that was for convience.